# Cannot rotate mesh in React Three Fiber

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I have a Plane mesh, and I want to have it initialised with an initial rotation vector. However, setting the `rotateX` prop does not work.

```
<mesh rotateX={1}>
   <planeGeometry args={[5, 5, 64, 64]} />
   <meshStandardMaterial />
</mesh>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

In react three fiber you access the properties of an object using -.
So it will be

```
<mesh rotation-x={1}>
   <planeGeometry args={[5, 5, 64, 64]} />
   <meshStandardMaterial />
</mesh>
```

Alternatively, you could pass the hole array [x, y, z].

```
 <mesh rotation={[1, 0, 0]}>
     <planeGeometry args={[5, 5, 64, 64]} />
     <meshStandardMaterial />
 </mesh>
```

Answer (score 5):

`rotation` arg is of type `Euler` and it takes a tuple (read array) of values:

As written in [docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Euler) about Euler:

> Euler( x : Float, y : Float, z : Float, order : String )
>
> - x - (optional) the angle of the x axis in radians. Default is 0.
> - y - (optional) the angle of the y axis in radians. Default is 0.
> - z - (optional) the angle of the z axis in radians. Default is 0.
> - order - (optional) a string representing the order that the rotations are applied, defaults to 'XYZ' (must be upper case).

For example, to rotate sphere by 90 deg around x axis, write the following:

```
<mesh rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]}>
  <planeGeometry args={[5, 5, 64, 64]} />
  <meshStandardMaterial />
</mesh>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using typescript, then you should try installing @types/three

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useRef()` to refer to that plane, then rotate it in the `useEffect` hook by calling it.

Example :

```
const planeRef = useRef();
useEffect(() => {
    planeRef && planeRef.current.rotation.x = 1.0 * Math.PI/180; // to convert from Deg to Rad.

}, []);

...
return (
<>
<mesh ref={planeRef}>
   <planeGeometry args={[5, 5, 64, 64]} />
   <meshStandardMaterial />
</mesh>
</>
);
```